Calculate SUM if criteria appears in a string in the criteria_range




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
1,4,7,10
500

1
560
(=500+60)


2
2,5,8,11
300

2
300
(=300)


3
3,6,9,12
800

3
800
(=800)


4
1,9
60

4
500
(=500)


5
5,12
90

5
390
(=300+90)


6
6,7,12
30

6
830
(=800+30)


7



7
530
(=500+30)


8



8
300
(=300)


9



9
860
(=800+60)


10



10
500
(=500)


11



11
300
(=300)


12



12
920
(=800+90+30)


13










As you can see in Column A the values in the cells are a string. 
In Column D each number that appears in Column A is listed separately. 
The idea is now to calculate the SUM in Column E whenever one of the numbers in Column D appears in a string in Column A. 
Something like this: 
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$6,If number in cell D1 appears in one of the strings in Column A)

(Note: I only added Column F for a better explanation how the numbers in Column E are calculated)

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Post is very clear. Shouldn't be downvoted. Per OP: In Column D each number that appears in Column A is listed separately.

Try using the following formula:


=MAP(D1:D12,LAMBDA(α,SUM(FILTER(B1:B6,1-ISERR(FIND(","&α&",",","&A1:A6&","))))))


Or, To copy down can use:
=SUM(FILTER(B$1:B$6,1-ISERR(FIND(","&D1&",",","&A$1:A$6&","))))


Or,
=SUM(IF(1-ISERR(FIND(","&D1&",",","&A$1:A$6&",")),B$1:B$6,0))




Formula in E1:
=MAP(D1:D12,LAMBDA(s,SUM(B1:B6*REGEXTEST(A1:A6,"\b"&s&"\b"))))

